# Strange SQL error, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and SQL, and for some reason I got this very strange and cryptic error.

> Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSER INTO history(stype, symbol, amount, price, time, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ' at line 1 in /home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/includes/functions.php on line 139

and this is the code that I use:

```
<?php 
require("../includes/config.php");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // Retrieve the requested user's symbol and calculate the stock's price
    $symbol = $_POST["symbol"];
    $price = lookup($symbol)["price"];
    // If lookup fails, apologize
    if ($price === null) {
    apologize("Sorry!");}
    // Retrieve user's cash balance
    $cash = query("select cash from users where id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
    foreach ($cash as $qux){$cash = $qux["cash"];}
    // Calculate the amount of money needed to buy the amount of stock
    $PayPrice = $_POST["SAmount"] * $price;
    // If user doesnt have enough cash, apologize
    if ($cash < $PayPrice){apologize("Your a cheapskate");}
    // If user enters a decimal or negative number, apologize
    if (preg_match("/^\d+$/", $_POST["SAmount"]) != true){apologize("Y u so decimal");}
    // Deduct the amount of cash from user's money   
    $result = query("UPDATE users SET cash = ? where id = ?", ($cash - $PayPrice), $_SESSION["id"]);
    if ($result === false){apologize("Update failed, cash");}
    // Update the user's stock
    $result = query("INSERT INTO stocks (id, symbol, stock) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock = stock + ?", $_SESSION['id'], $_POST["symbol"], $_POST["SAmount"], $_POST["SAmount"]);
    if ($result === false){apologize("Update failed, stock");}
    // Update history
    $result = query("INSER INTO history(stype, symbol, amount, price, time, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 'buy', $symbol, $_POST['SAmount'], $PayPrice, time(), $_SESSION['id']);

}
else{render("BuyPage.php");}

?>
```

and here is the query() code

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
    {
        // SQL statement
        $sql = func_get_arg(0);

        // parameters, if any
        $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

        // try to connect to database
        static $handle;
        if (!isset($handle))
        {
            try
            {
                // connect to database
                $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
                $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                // trigger (big, orange) error
                trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
                exit;
            }
        }

        // prepare SQL statement
        $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
        if ($statement === false)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }

        // execute SQL statement
        $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

        // return result set's rows, if any
        if ($results !== false)
        {
            return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This problem is strangely cryptic as I have no idea what is going on, I included all the code that i thought was needed but if more is needed please do tell me. 
Ps: Needless to say, the problem originated only after I input the very last line of SQL code for inserting into history, else everything else was working fine and good.

Comment: Yes yes, *very* cryptic. `INSER INTO` - My suggestion is, you start to *read* error messages more carefully from now on.

Comment: Pro tip: when the error message says that you have an error in your SQL syntax, consider the possible explanation that you have an error in your SQL syntax.

(I will concede that those messages are irritatingly imprecise about where the problem is, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$result = query("INSER INTO history(stype, symbol, amount, price, time, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 'buy', $symbol, $_POST['SAmount'], $PayPrice, time(), $_SESSION['id']);
```

With:

```
$result = query("INSERT INTO history(stype, symbol, amount, price, time, userid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 'buy', $symbol, $_POST['SAmount'], $PayPrice, time(), $_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: If you're wondering what he changed, you'd put `INSER` rather than `INSERT`.